# Styling react-select with CSS modules works on Sandbox but not on local machine

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass, css-modules

The ['Using ClassNames' section](https://react-select.com/styles#using-classnames) of [`react-select`](https://react-select.com) docs states that using the `className` and `classNamePrefix` props

> ensures compatibility with styled components, **CSS modules** and
> other libraries.

In [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-mountain-wip00), with CSS modules and `node-sass`, it seems to work. However, if I replicate the following code on my local machine in a create-react-app, it doesn't work. My CRA uses the Typescript template. Is that the problem? Everything else is just the same.

`Select.module.scss`

```
.select {
  outline: 1px solid red;

  .select__control {
    background-color: salmon;
  }
}
```

---

`Select.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import RS from 'react-select';
import style from './Select.module.scss';

const options = [
  {label: "hi", value: "hi"}
]

function Select(props: any) {
  return (
    <RS
      options={options}
      className={style.select}
      classNamePrefix={style.select}
    />
  )
}

export default Select;
```

---

`App.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from './Select';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Probably in your project css-module is hashing in the end of class name, like: `{select: "styles_select__SQ71h", select__control: "styles_select__control__xcj2p"}` but react-select wants something like `{select: "styles_select__SQ71h", select__control: "styles_select__SQ71h__control"}`

Answer (score 12):

I could make it work here by doing:

`Select.module.scss`

```
.select {
  outline: 1px solid red;

  [class$="-control"] {
    background-color: salmon;
  }
}
```

`Select.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import RS from 'react-select';
import style from './Select.module.scss';

const options = [
  {label: "hi", value: "hi"}
]

function Select(props: any) {
  return (
    <RS
      options={options}
      className={style.select}
    />
  )
}

export default Select;
```

Basically, I removed `classNamePrefix` from react-select component and changed `.select__control` to `[class$="-control"]`, which matches all classes ending with `-control`.

The problem here was because css loader was adding a hash in my classnames eg `{select: "styles_select__SQ71h", select__control: "styles_select__control__xcj2p"}`.